# Is a typeclass constraint discouraged in a typeclass method?

Tags: haskell

I know that **constraints in data** are discouraged in Haskell. For instance,

```
data Eq b => Bar b = Bar b
```

is not possible without a deprecated extension. I also hear that even

```
data Bar b = Eq b => Bar b
```

is not common and even discouraged. (Is this right BTW?)

---

Is the same true for **constraints in typeclasses**? For instance, is doing something like

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: Eq b => a -> b
```

discouraged in Haskell as well? Is it commonly seen in real code?

Comment: I'd say it's not discouraged and not very common. If you need that, that's fine as far as I can see.

Comment: `data Bar b = Eq b => Bar b` is not discouraged, per se, but it's much more commonly written using GADT syntax: `data Bar b where Bar :: Eq b => Bar b`. This particular one is actually more likely to be expressed using `Data.Constraint`: `type Bar b = Dict (Eq b)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typeclass method is, from a usage perspective, no different from an ordinary polymorphic function which just happens to have that class as a constraint on one ([or more](https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class)) of in its participant type variables. But there may be other type variables in the signature which need other constraints not supplied by the one class head. Constraints are (usually) *necessary for you to be able to implement the function*, so, it's certainly reasonable to need constraints on class methods – unlike constraints on `data` types, which actually serve no purpose at all (the implementation of a `data` is just some data layout, it can't possibly need any methods from any classes<sup>†</sup>).

However, you can avoid this issue by including the extra constrained type variables in the class head:

```
class (Eq b) => Foo b a where
  foo :: a -> b
```

Sometimes, this is better than your proposal, but sometimes it's certainly not better, for instance if `Foo` has a whole bunch of methods and of these only one is concerned with `b` at all. Of course in that case it would also be possible to split off only `foo` into a subclass that has `b` in its head, and leave the other methods in a class without extra constraints. But having two classes instead of one may also not be so nice.

Therefore, I would consider it perfectly legitimate to add constraints to class methods, if you find yourself in a situation where this is a natural thing to do.

Existing examples of methods which have such constraints are [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap), [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) and [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift). It's not a ubiquitous pattern, but definitely not totally uncommon either.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>This looks a bit different if you consider type/data families, but even then you don't need constraints on `data` but just the functions that deal with this data.</sub>

Comment: While datatype contexts are utterly useless, constraints on data constructors are not.

Comment: @dfeuer: yeah, in the form of GADTs.